# Azure Synapse Analytics - Dedicated Pool - Create user - Incorrect syntax near 'PASSWORD'

Tags: azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

I'm trying to create a Contained Users in Synapse Dedicated Pool using the below command

```
create user [username]
with password = 'Comple@xPassword@123'
default_schema = 'dbo'
```

It's failing with the below error message

> Parse error at line: 3, column: 2: Incorrect syntax near 'PASSWORD'.

It works fine in Azure SQL Database. However, it fails in Synapse Dedicated Pool. Any help in appreciated.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: “ SQL Database supports contained database users using SQL Server authentication, but Azure Synapse Analytics does not.”  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation:

“*SQL Database supports contained database users using SQL Server authentication, but Azure Synapse Analytics does not.*”

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver16